# Pig script to count the number of letters in a file

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

I want to extend the hello world program of hadoop word count to be able to count the number of letters in the input file.

I have written this so far and I'm unable to figure out what is wrong with this code. Any help identifying the issue will be appreciated.

```
A = load '/tmp/alice.txt';
B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;
C = filter B by word matches '\\w+';
D = foreach C generate flatten(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(word, '([a-zA-Z])')) as letter;
E = group D by letter;
F = foreach E generate COUNT(D), group;
store F into '/tmp/alice_wordcount';
```

Comment: By number of letters I mean the count of the number of occurrences of each letter.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 3):

Let me say that I am a PIG newbie, but somehow this query got me interested. I diverged into all kinds of complex stuff like nested `foreach`, UDFs etc. But in the end, the answer is pretty simple. It's just a correction in one of your pig latin lines as below:

```
D = foreach C generate flatten(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(word,'','|'), '|')) as letter;
```

Instead of using `regexp_extract_all`, I instead opt to `REPLACE` each letter boundary with a special character (`'|'` here, though you can use an uncommon sequence also if you like) and then `TOKENIZE` around that delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

Load the data `A = load '/tmp/alice.txt';`

Split the line into words `B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;`

Split words into chars `C = foreach B generate flatten(TOKENIZE(REPLACE($0,'','|'),'|')) as letter;`

Group the letters `D = GROUP C BY letter;`

Generate the results with count of each letter `E = foreach D generate COUNT(C), group;`

`Store F into '/tmp/alice_wordcount';`